# List<Uint8List> to List<int> in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

does anyone know how to convert a `List<Uint8List>` to a `List<int>`. I want to use it with the library Google Speech (Speech to Text using google api) and to use it I need to give the audio data with the format `List<int>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Uint8List` derives from `List<int>`, so no conversion would be necessary if you have start from just a `Uint8List`.

If, as you say, you have a `List<Uint8List>`, you would need to combine them into a single `List`.  One way to do that:

```dart
final mergedList = [
  for (var sublist in listOfLists)
    ...sublist,
];
```

Depending on exactly what you're doing, there might be better, more specialized alternatives (e.g. [`collectBytes` from `package:async`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/collectBytes.html)).