# The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, bluetooth, data-transfer

Im using this code to send data via bluetooth with flutter and i have two questions.

First of all I am getting this error message which I dont know how to fix, the erros is this:

"The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'".

here is the code:

```
void _sendMessage(String value1) async {
    value1 = value1.trim();
    if(value1.length >0){
      try{
        connection.output.add(utf8.encode(value1));
        await connection.output.allSent;
      }catch(e){
        setState(() { });


      }
    }
  }
```

the compiler highlights **utf8.encode(value1)** as the error

My second question is how i can alter this code to send integers instead of string

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.fromList.html

Comment: as pskink pointed you can use `Uint8List.fromList(
List<int> elements
)` to convert List<int> to Uint8List.

Comment: Try using `as Uint8List` first.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163916/.

Comment: convert your list to uint8list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295468/listuint8list-to-listint-in-dart

Comment: Thank you all. I did convert my list with fromList and the error is not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somethin like this init

```
  //send string
  void _sendMessageString(String value1) async {
    value1 = value1.trim();
    if (value1.length > 0) {
      try {
        List<int> list = value1.codeUnits;
        Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);
        connection.output.add(bytes);
        await connection.output.allSent;
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }
  

  //send int
  void _sendMessageInt(int value1) async {
    try {
      Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(value1);
      connection.output.add(bytes);
      await connection.output.allSent;
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```